# Activated and Deactivate

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I have a MDI Windows Forms application. The main form, among the other events, have following two: Activated and Deactivate. And the problem is that they trigger each other cyclically (event if the event handlers for them are empty). IntelliTrace show me nothing except calling handlers for those events one after another. I don't understand, why it is happening. Any idea about it?

Comment: Please provide the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that the answer is obvious. They trigger each other because of Visual studio debugger. When it step into an Activated event handler, it causes deactivate event. Then it goes into an Deactivate event handler after which Activated event is raised again. So, it is just sort of thing which hard to debug by using common methods.

Comment: If you asked the question, I would assume you wouldn't think the answer was that easy. If you did manage to find an answer to your question before everyone else, I would suggest you word the answer so that it is clearer that you are submitting your own answer.